# How do Fractal of the Mist monsters scale?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Ok we all know that every tier of Fractal level increases agony. This seems the main problem in dealing with high level fractals, but what about the monsters?

Looking at a dredge Fractal (which by the way is the second most hated by me), At level 2 there were 2 monsters guarding the side press platform. While at level 4 they were only 3 or 4 monsters, at level 8 they were about 6. We see they increase in number and this makes it harder, which is fine.

I never played above level 8, but now I'm wondering, if at level 8 we have tripled the monster number compared to level 2, Does the amount of monsters keep growing at this rate or does the monster count remain the same because agony starts kicking in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of enemies does not scale that dramatically. You can read about the differences [on the wiki](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Fractals_of_the_mists#Difficulty_scale), but the main difference in difficulty is that the enemies become more powerful. This is done by slightly increasing their levels or numbers, adding new attacks at higher difficulties, or buffing certain attributes (such as the movement speed of the veteran grawl in the volcanic fractal).

The increase in number of enemies that you observed seems abnormally high; the increased numbers are usually subtle. That observed difference may be related to those dredge respawning indefinitely. To answer your question: yes they will keep increasing steadily, but not nearly as quickly as you've described.

Note that only bosses inflict [agony](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Agony), so additional agony and increased enemy numbers will rarely be coinciding problems.

Comment: At the start of the Dredge fractal you have to run up on side platforms to open the frontal gates, so you have to split the party, and on the upper platform I found out a high increase in mob numbers... anyway... after level 10, with agony kicking in, does the mob power/quantity still increase from level 9?

Comment: The dredge who attack you while you hold down the switches respawn indefinitely. They should cap out at 3-5, so 6 seems like a lot, especially for a low fractal level. After level 9 the power and quantity will continue to increase. Keep in mind that only bosses inflict agony, so it makes sense for other enemies to be stronger at higher levels.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect your response and more directly answer your question.

Comment: Thanks, now it's clearer, it is possible that my perception of high increase is due to jumping from level 2 to level 8, once... :)